# KVO on the iPhone on 3.0 vs 2.2.1, having an issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, key-value-observing

Appears the 3.0 NDA has been lifted, so this should be safe to ask. If this is violating an NDA, please let me know so I can remove the post, post-haste.

I have a very trivial implementation for KVO on an NSOperationQueue. My problem is that when compiling against 2.2.1 SDK, I get different results for the NSOperationQueue in question for a device using 3.0 or one using 2.2.1. I've confirmed this on 1 iPod Touch that has 2.2.1, one that has 3.0, and two sets of iPhones with similar setups.

The code looks like this:

```
// set observer
[self.myOperationQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"operations" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

// implementation
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context 
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"]) {
      NSInteger operationCount = [[(NSOperationQueue*)object operations] count];
      NSArray *operations = [(NSOperationQueue*)object operations];
    }
}
```

As per the code above, the device running 3.0 will return the correct operationCount and the correct operations. A device running 2.2.1 will always return nil for operations and 0 for operationCount.

Can't seem to pin point why this is the case. All builds are compiled against 2.2.1.

NOTE

As per Matt's response below; 'object' is nil on 2.2.1. It is not nil on 3.0.

Comment: Try using NSLog() to check the value of the object, not GDB. I've run into a strange problem building for 2.2.1 with the Xcode 3.1.3: http://www.openradar.me/7017295

Answer (score 1):

The values you're getting sound like the `object` parameter is literally `nil`. To find the source of the problem, you may wish to check that `object` and `self.myOperationQueue` are the same value -- if they are then your `self.myOperationQueue` is just in a weird state. If they're not equal, then you can just read from `self.myOperationQueue` instead of `object`.

However, you are using the `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` option but you're not reading the value that it gives you. The point of `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` is that it passes the new value in the change dictionary.

i.e.

```
// Inside the observe method
NSArray *newOperationsArray = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
```

If you don't want to extract the new value from the change dictionary, you don't need to pass the `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` value (you can just pass 0).

Comment: Hey Matt, you're most certainly right when you guessed that object is nil. I'm baffled as to why object is nil when it's ran on a 2.2.1 device but not on a 3.0 device..